# Check in selected files in TFS programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, checkin

I want to check in files to TFS, but not all in my pending changes.

```
PendingChange[] changes = workspace.GetPendingChanges();
workspace.CheckIn(changes, "");
```

In this way i check in all my files. But i only want to check in selected files with a specific file name. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering `changes` list based on `PendingChange.FileName` or other property. Then call `Workspace.CheckIn` with filtered changes list.